# Android app crashing on using editText

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and I'm trying to make an app that sends some data from a secondary activity to the initial one and after the data is sent the second activity is closed. Problem is I get this error when compiling

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

```
public void sendData(View view)
{   
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String msg = new String("");
    String msg2 = new String("");
    Intent intent1;
    intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    msg = editText1.getText().toString();
    msg2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    bundle.putString(extra_message,msg);
    bundle.putString(extra_message2,msg2);
    intent1.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent1);
    finish();
}
```

I've seen other posts related to this. I've tried to initialize the strings that capture the value of the `editText` yet it says its null and causes my app to crash. Below I have the code that conjures my listview and some items and the point is to add another element from the second activity:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
String[] itemsToBeDisplayed = {"Vezi Doctor", "Cumparaturi", "Facturi", "Datorie"};
arrayList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(itemsToBeDisplayed));
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_items,R.id.txtitem,arrayList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String new_note = bundle.getString(Add_note.extra_message);
String notes = bundle.getString(Add_note.extra_message2);
arrayList.add(new_note);
```

It is within the `onCreate` Method. The rest of the code works just fine.

Comment: `editText1` is `null` probably not calling `setContentView` or Edttext is not available in provided layout for First Activity

Comment: Probably your problem is that your editText1 or editText2 are null, so you can't find this field. Put a log and see 
Try
(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

Comment: Or your name is wrong. Maybe you want to get editText1
 (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Comment: `try {
            EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            Log.e("MyApplication","Exception Confirmed",exception);
        }` I put this in and I got something like this `11-02 20:14:11.020 1294-1308/system_process E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader:     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$MyHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsImpl.java:156)`

Comment: Not used to debugging as I said I'm really new so sorry if I do it wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think: In order to pass data, such as bundles, you need to also set a variable name, not just a value. What about :

```
  intent1.putExtras("blabla",bundles);
```